# Java - substring via scanner input to receive corresponding information

Tags: java, file, arraylist, substring

I'm aiming to add edit functionality to a film collection which allows the user to pick a film and it's corresponding information via it's film name (chosen by the user via a scanner) and store it into a string where the user is able to replace and update film information.

I have an ArrayList storing information as follows;

```
Film Name:- 9, Film Duration (in mins):- 92, Film Release Year:- 2009, Rating Out of 5:- 4
...
```

I have converted the ArrayList into a string using `.toString()` and depending on the input from the user. The film and it's corresponding information will be stored into a separate string.

My issue is that I am unsure how to use the scanner and substring operations properly in order to get the desired result.

This is what I've got so far;

```
while (editInterface) {
                if (editArrayString.toLowerCase().contains(editScannerInput.toLowerCase())) {
                    String chosenFilm = editArrayString.substring(editArrayString.contains(editScannerInput), editArrayString.length() - 1);
                    System.out.println(chosenFilm);
                    editInterface = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Film name is not recognised in your collection, please enter a film name that is in your collection.");
                }
            }
            while (editInterfaceAttribute) {
                System.out.println("Which film attribute would you like to edit?");
                if (editScannerInput.equals("Name".toLowerCase())) {
                    film.promptFilmName();
                    String newFilmName = film.getFilmName();
                } else if (editScannerInput.equals("Duration".toLowerCase())){
                    film.promptFilmDuration();
                    int newFilmDuration = film.getDurationInMins();
                } else if (editScannerInput.equals("Year".toLowerCase())) {
                    film.promptFilmYear();
                    int newFilmYear = film.getFilmReleaseYear();
                } else if (editScannerInput.equals("Rating".toLowerCase())) {
                    film.promptFilmRating();
                    int newFilmRating = film.getFilmRatingOutOfFive();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Your input is not an attribute, please enter an attribute.");
                }
            }
```

I know that the first if statement is completely incorrect as I'm not sure how to store a film's information into a string via substring. So any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the input you are expecting and what do you want to extract from those exactly ? PS: You should use a `Map` instead of that `List` of concatenated `key:- value`, this would be simpler to get the value back for a specific key..

Comment: The input has to match a film name that is in the collection, and I want to extract the information in the same format at the top of the question based on what film name was inputted.

Comment: Please [edit] the question with an example of what you want, not only the explanation. If you want the user to input `9` and then you should print `Film Name:- 9, Film Duration (in mins):- 92, Film Release Year:- 2009, Rating Out of 5:- 4` since the name of the film is the one asked. Then this is just about searching a `Film` instance in a `List<Film>`, but this is unclear without a [mcve]. (Mostly the part about the list.... how do you store the values? )

Comment: The values in the list are defined in a separate class and added from a separate method (also using Scanner). They are added into a string which is then saved into a text file for permanent storage, they called back using a scanner that reads each line of the file.